# Why is there a negative sample space in this probability question?

Tags: probability

So there are multiple ways of solving the following problem but when I try the table method this happens:

Given $A$ and $B$ are events of a sample space $S$ and $P(A\cap B) = \frac{2}{5}$ and $P(A\cap B') = \frac{3}{7}$ then what is $P(B'\mid A)$?

My table looks like this

|  | A | B |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 14 | 29 |
| B | 14 | ??? | 6 |
|  | 29 | 6 | 35 |

$B$ would have to have a negative value which is impossible. Any help?

Comment: No, but I see I used a $\cup $ instead of a $\cap$. Let me fix that

Comment: I would have expected A and A' as the columns, with B and B' as the rows.

Comment: @Peter ahhh yes that is correct. Thanks

Comment: Oh, is $B'$ the complementary event to $B$? Different books use different notation for that.

Answer (score 2):

You have been promised that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=14/35, \mathsf P(A\cap B')=15/35$, which entails that $\mathsf P(A)=29/35$ and hence $\mathsf P(A')=6/35$.

However we have no way to evaluate $\mathsf P(B)$.   All we can say is that $14\leqslant\mathsf P(B)\leqslant 20$.

We might indicate that $\mathsf P(B\cap A')=x/35$ for some unknown $x: 0\leqslant x\leqslant 6$.

Hence the table shall be:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c:c|c|}\hline &A&A'\\[1ex]\hline B&14&x&14+x\\[1ex]\hdashline B'&15&6-x&21-x\\[1ex]\hline & 29& 6&35\\\hline\end{array}$$

Now, you can use this table to evaluate $\mathsf P(B'\mid A)$....